# Add Padding using MPAndroid's Line chart

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid Chart library, my problem is as seen in below screenshot, I want that years 2016 & 2017 should have some kind of padding so that it doesn't look congested. If someone can guide me to this, I gone through the documentation mentioned on https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki but couldn't find any change.

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Buddy which version of library you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

it is not exactly what you want, but I think it is something similar and can be used
It has paddings from both sides, If the solution works for you, here is code

[image]

```
mChart.getAxisRight().setXOffset(30);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setXOffset(30);
mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);    
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

Comment: I am not getting the desired output, what I need is there should be some distance kept from LHS of 2016 & RHS of 2017. Even if I add some dummy values to start like "2015" or keep it blank, it also plots that value, which is not expected output.

Comment: @Sagarmehta, please check this link may be it's help to you.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1273

Comment: yAxis.setXOffset(...) method helped, also I used yAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false) which removed the Y axis line which now shows data pretty as expected.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Sagar if you like my efforts behind getting your solution. Then please please give me upvote and accept my answer. I feeling glad to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used v2.1.6 of mpAndroid and following code creates your desired result:

```
LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    entries.add(new Entry(500 ,1));
    entries.add(new Entry(5000, 2));

    LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("2015");
    labels.add("2016");
    labels.add("2017");
    labels.add("2018");

    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
    lineChart.setData(data);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

[image]

Comment: you can further change colors as per your requirements

Comment: Do let me know for further assistance also let me know if it works buddy

Comment: @MSaadLakhan I am already getting the result what you have posted, but I need the expected output shown above, as mentioned in my comments  above I got the desired output..

Comment: My mistake you want to achieve the second one?

Comment: Look at it if it helps you let me know and for further help to change anything do let me know mate.Happy coding :)

Comment: Your way will also do, currently I have done it other way as mentioned earlier, will try this way if required. Will let you know if I stuck anywhere. Happy coding :)

Comment: Best of luck mate :)